# Animated UIView's contents not receiving touch events

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I've got a UIView which the user drags on and off of the screen (like a drawer).
The UIView has a bunch of buttons, some always visible, others hidden until the user 'opens' the drawer.

For some reason, the UIButtons that are 'off screen' on the initial UIView presentation aren't being passed events when they're later moved onto screen.
While the others receive all the events all the time.

Seems buggy to me, I would have thought the SDK would handle all this itself?

I've got a very simple example which you can take a look at: http://cl.ly/2r1c0k2p361B3B1A461L

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May this will help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311645/uiview-touchesbegan-doesnt-respond-during-animation

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research, it had to do with the views clipping boundaries.

The buttons were being drawn, but were essentially out of the views frame, so no events were registered.

More details on this question: [Programmatically Created UIButtons Below Screen Not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140817/programmatically-created-uibuttons-below-screen-not-working)